# Move and modify holes in an object

Tags: modeling, modifiers

If I want to cut a hole (for example for a window in a wall of house) in an object I usually use a boolean modifier to do so. However is there a simple way to move, resize or remove the hole afterwards?

Comment: It really depends on your object, it may not be easy

Comment: In my case it are rectangular holes in cuboids (for example walls) or in another case circular holes in cuboids. How about that cases?

Comment: if boolean works, use it, but it may not work fine with every topology, maybe show some screenshots of your object and topology

Comment: If you don't apply the modifier you can move or remove your hole by simply moving or deleting the Boolean object that created it.

Comment: Dealing with boolean'd geometry can be messy, they tend to produce bad topology that's hard to tweak afterwards so I either wouldn't apply the boolean and keep the cutting object around for later, or cut by hand ensuring good topology

Comment: @JohnEason: I tried it, and it seems to work. Are there any side effects by not applying the modifiers? Suppose you have created a house with lots of windows and some doors. Then I want to be able to move or resize windows or doors later without trouble.

Comment: Being able to alter your model later is one of the reasons for not applying modifiers, so no there wouldn't normally be any side effects.

Comment: @JohnEason: Ok, thanks. Maybe you could turn your comment into an answer, then I can accept it. By the way: Is there a way to apply all modifiers (on all objects) at same time in one step (and also undo this in one step)?

Comment: Those are really general knowledge answers that you should be able to pick up with general Blender tutorials so I'm not sure they really merit a full answer here. I'll address your other questions in another comment.

Comment: There's a built-in addon which you can enable that allows you to apply all modifiers to an object at once plus a couple of other modifier functions. Details are in the Blender manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/addons/interface/modifier_tools.html). You can also apply all modifiers to all objects at once using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBMtInpdeAU) method although I've never used it myself. The only way to undo an applied modifier is to use CTRL-Z immediately after you've applied it.